# How to reduce docker pull time during CI build?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I use GitLab Runner on my Kubernetes cluster to run CI jobs. I want to make build jobs run faster.

To make them faster, I reuse Docker image from the previous build (tagged as `latest`). Build time has decreased, but now the bottleneck is the `pull` command which takes about 60-70% of the time.

Here's the snippet of the `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
build:sheets:
  stage: build
  image: docker:stable
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" "$CI_REGISTRY" --password-stdin
  script:
    - docker pull $SHEETS_LATEST || true
    - docker build --cache-from $SHEETS_LATEST --tag $SHEETS_TAG --tag $SHEETS_LATEST .
    - docker push $SHEETS_TAG
    - docker push $SHEETS_LATEST
```

I use Gitlab Registry and thus `pull` command requires a lot of communication between my cluster and the registry.

So I have a couple of questions here:

1. **Is it worth effort to deploy my own docker registry on the cluster to save a couple of minutes per build?**
2. **Is there a way to save an image somewhere on cluster to not pull from registry every time?**

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods to build Docker images in Pipeline quicker.

1. DOOD (Docker out of Docker)

Here you've to mount host's /var/lib/docker.sock inside your build container. It is vulnerable. But still too fast.

2. DIND (Docker in Docker)

Here you can use dind image which has both docker cli and daemon. It doesn't communicate to host's docker daemon. The entire build process will happen within the pod. Not 100% secure but faster.

3. Kaniko, Makisu, Buildah

These are Daemoneless next-generation image build tools and which does not depend on Docker daemon. More secure than DOOD and DIND also faster and supports caching.

Comment: Thank you for the overview, but that does not explain how to use it in GitLab CI.

Answer (score 0):

You can run dedicated pod with Docker daemon inside with persistent volume mounted to /var/lib/docker. After that you expose this pod using service named for example "docker". After that in your CI jobs you define environment variable "DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker".

That way all your builds and images are stored in Docker daemon running in dedicated pod. You don't lose time pulling images and also you builds run faster because of Docker build cache.

Just remember to monitor disk space usage on persistent volume and trigger "docker system prune" periodically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but could you please explain how to start such a pod in GitLab Runner?

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab shared runners don't have your previous image available (as you noticed).  So your options are either pull it like you are doing, or go with your own runners.  Last time I looked, it wasn't available with the kubernetes runner that you can install on the gitlab kubernetes integration page, so I had to deploy my own runners.

Here is a deployment that creates 4 runners (todo: figure out autoscaling) and registers them as a postStart event.  You'll need to get your registration token from your settings/cicd page for your project or group (https://gitlab.com/[user]/[project]/settings/ci_cd).  And you'll have to disable shared runners from the same page.

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gitlabrunner
  labels:
    app: gitlabrunner
spec:
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: gitlabrunner
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gitlabrunner
      name: gitlabrunner
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: gitlabrunner
        image: gitlab/gitlab-runner
        volumeMounts:
        - name: dockersock
          mountPath: "/var/run/docker.sock"
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "gitlab-runner register -n --url https://gitlab.com/ --registration-token [YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN] --executor docker --description 'My Docker Runner' --docker-image 'docker:stable' --docker-volumes /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"]
      volumes:
      - name: dockersock
        hostPath:
          path: /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: I don't use GitLab shared runners. I have deployed them to my cluster with Helm. The question is how to save images inside the cluster so that I can avoid extra communication with the registry.